# K-Arms Bandit Epsilon-Greedy Policy

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have been trying to implement Reinforcement Learning books exercise 2.5

I have written this piece of code according to this pseudo version

[image]

```
class k_arm:
    def __init__(self, iter, method="incrementally"):

        # self.iter placeholder
        self.iter = iter
        self.k = 10
        self.eps = .1
        
        # here is Q(a) and N(a)
        self.qStar = np.zeros(self.k)
        self.n = np.zeros(self.k)
        
        # Method just for experimenting different functions
        self.method = method
        
    def pull(self):
        
        # selecting argmax(Q(A)) action with prob. (1 - eps)
        eps = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1)
        if eps < self.eps or self.qStar.argmax() == 0:
            a = np.random.randint(10)
        else: a = self.qStar.argmax()
        
        # R bandit(A)
        r = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, 1)
        
        # N(A) <- N(A) + 1
        self.n[a] += 1
        
        # Q(A) <- Q(A) i / (N(A)) * (R - Q(A))
        if self.method == "incrementally":
            self.qStar[a] +=  (r - self.qStar[a]) / self.n[a] 
            return self.qStar[a]`
```

```
iter = 1000
rewards = np.zeros(iter)
c = k_arm(iter, method="incrementally")

for i in range(iter):    
    k = c.pull()
    rewards[i] = k
```

And I get this as a result

[image]

Where I am expecting this kind of results.

[image]

I have been trying to understand where am I went missing here, but I couldn't.

Comment: why are you testing for `or self.qStar.argmax() == 0`

Comment: initial ```self.qStar``` is zero arrays, so in order to choose randomly at the first iteration, ```np.argmax(np.zeros(n))``` returns to zero, since there is no maximum valued element in it. Also, it works if there is the multiple same maximum valued element by any chance

Comment: this might cause problems with the action selection. consider removing it, how you sleect the first action usually doesn't matter after a few examples.

Comment: I have identified the issue and added a detailed explanation as an answer @merkwur

Comment: you may consider it as a tie-breaker. if the tie is the case in ```argmax```, returns the random selection (but considering the random float numbers, tie chance is basically 0)

Comment: Now I get it, it is going to cause a problem when the 0th element is the maximum argument.

Comment: Exactly, if your most likely action is action 0, you do a random action instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your average reward is around 0 because it is the correct estimation. Your reward function is defined as:

```
 # R bandit(A)
 r = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, 1)
```

This means the expected value of your reward distribution is 0 with 0.01 variance. In the book the authors use a different reward function. While this **still has a fundamental issue**, you could earn similar rewards if you change your code to

```
 # R bandit(A)
 r = np.random.normal(1.25, 0.01, 1)
```

It makes sense to give **each bandit a different reward function** or **all your action values will be the same**. So what you really should do is sample from `k` different distributions with different expected values. Otherwise action selection is meaningless.
Add this to your `init` function:

```
self.expected_vals = np.random.uniform(0, 2, self.k)
```

and change the the calculation of the reward so, that it depends on the action:

```
r = np.random.uniform(self.expected_vals[a], 0.5, 1)
```

I've also increased the variance to 0.5 as 0.01 is basically meaningless variance in the context of bandits. If your agents works correctly, his average reward should be approximately equal to `np.max(self.expected_vals)`